# Hindu astronomy mapping with western astronomy

Tags: astronomy

I am looking for sources to map the name of stars and constellation followed by Indian astronomy with the western one. Any references would be welcome.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakshatra

Comment: thank you. that was a good one that helped me to get a start. Any further reading materials would be helpful for next level.